# Using Facebook Javascript SDK to see if visitor is fan without logging in

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to see if a visitor is a fan of the page linked to our current website? We use the Javascript SDK.

```
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : '000000000',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true,
        channelURL : 'http://www.google.com/channel.php',
        oauth  : true
    });


};
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?= $site['locale'] ?>/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
}(document));
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can see if the visitor of your website is a fan by authenticating them to your app with the user_likes permission granted, then you can use a variety of ways via the Graph API objects or FQL statements to determine this.